# Can iTextSharp 5.5.9 open a PDF which has been 256-bit encrypted?

Tags: encryption, itext

I am getting error "Unknown encryption type R=6" when attempting to instantiate a PDFReader:

```
var reader = new PdfReader(bytearray, new AsciiEncoding().GetBytes(ownerPassword));
```

I can see that iTextSharp can encrypt at 256-bits but can it decrypt?

P.S. The PDF was encrypted using Acrobat Pro XI.

Comment: bit level shouldn't matter, but the crypt algorithm DOES. if the pdf is crypted using algo "foo", and support for "foo" was added in a version LATER than 5.5.9, then there's nothing you can do about that other than upgrading to a version that does support that algo.

Comment: iText only supports up to R=5 which had been introduced in the Adobe Extension to ISO 32000-1, ExtensionLevel 3 for AES-256. In the upcoming ISO 32000-2 R=5 shall not be used ("This value was used by a deprecated
Adobe extension.") and instead R=6 will be used for a 256 bit key length, most likely with slight algorithm changes. Some PDF producer (Adobe?) seems ahead of time and already uses R=6.

Comment: Thank you. I have not followed the progress of ISO 32000 because I've only recently been put on a project that involves PDFs. Is 32000 nearing ratification? Is it expected to happen by the end of 2016? If not, we may have to change our plans dramatically.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone dares to promise a soon finalisation of ISO 32000-2, it should already have been finalised a number of years ago after all.